# In Symfony2 routing, how do I setup an optional subdomain

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a few subdomains that I use in my project, and I would like to have the main marketing site accept www as well as a blank subdomain

http://www.example.com & http://example.com

How can I achieve this with symfony?

This is my current setup

```
_main:
    resource: routing.yml

incompass_sterilization:
    host:     spd.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassSterilizationBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_printing:
    host:     labels.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassPrintingBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_admin:
    host:     admin.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassAdminBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_web:
    host:     www.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
```

I looked at the documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html but I can only see how to setup different subdomains that exist, I can't work out how to use an empty subdomain.

**edit**
duplicating the routes does not work, I can't get multiple routes to use the same controller. Here are 2 examples that did not solve the issue

Using the same routes file

```
incompass_web:
    host:     www.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_web_two:
    host:     casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
```

Using separate routes files

```
incompass_web:
    host:     www.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_web_two:
    host:     casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes_two.yml"
```

routes.yml

```
incompass_web_main:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    resource: Incompass\WebBundle\Controller\MainController
```

routes_two.yml

```
incompass_web_main_two:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    resource: Incompass\WebBundle\Controller\MainController
```

Comment: Couldn't you just duplicate the routes for the main domain?

Comment: that doesn't work, I've added the things I tried to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to use different types of routing.

app/config/routing.yml

```
_main:
    resource: routing.yml

incompass_sterilization:
    host:     spd.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassSterilizationBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_printing:
    host:     labels.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassPrintingBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_admin:
    host:     admin.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassAdminBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_web:
    host:     www.casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"

incompass_web_two:
    host:     casechek-dev.com
    resource: "@IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes_two.yml"
```

IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml

```
incompass_web_main:
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
    resource: Incompass\WebBundle\Controller\MainController
```

IncompassWebBundle/Resources/config/routes_two.yml

```
incompass_web_main_two:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: IncompassWebBundle:Main:index }
```